# How to use cycript to investigate a mach-o x86_64 binary?

Tags: osx

I recently found out about a tool called cycript that apparently does runtime analysis of binaries written with Objective-C.  I have a Mac OS X binary that is compiled as x86_64 and is intended to run on Intel Macs.  I know cycript is intended to for iOS applications but I wouldn't mind using it on this binary to poke around and see what is going on inside the binary.  Most instructions I see for cycript state to start off with UIApp, and then investigating further objects from there.

My problem is when I try to investigate UIApp with cycript I get the following error message,

`ReferenceError: hasProperty callback returned true for a property that doesn't exist.`

I am assuming I am getting this error message because the binary does not have a UIApp class / method in it because it is a Mac OS X binary and not an iOS.

Where would be a good starting point for using cycript with a Mac OS X binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIApp` is a shorthand for `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`.

As this is not an iOS app, but an OS X app you need to use `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` instead.

Comment: Similarly to `UIApp`, You can also use `NSApp` as shorthand for `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/nsapp